# Android - application not found error for some users after update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I have an android app on play store. I just released a new version but some of users report that after update they cant open application because they get application not installed error but they can open application through market by touching on open button. On new version i used same .jks file, I changed AndroidManifest.xml because i wanted to change main activity from .MainActivity to .Landing so mainActivity is no longer main. Maybe problem happens because of that? By the way not all users effected from this problem. Here is old and new AndroidManifest files and could you please check these files? Maybe another row cause that problem?

Solitions;
- Some users restart their phone and it works
- But some users cant fix by restarting their phone, so they remove and install again to fix it

But why this happens to some users?

OLD AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.example"
    android:versionCode="9"
    android:versionName="2.0.0"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission android:name="com.test.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.test.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity  android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Contact" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Notes"  android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>



    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.test.example" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />

    <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>



</manifest>
```

NEW AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.example"
    android:versionCode="10"
    android:versionName="2.0.1"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission android:name="com.test.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.test.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity  android:name=".Landing" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Contact" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Notes"  android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>



    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.test.example" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />

    <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: have you changed min sdk version ?

Comment: no i didn't change it

Comment: Your MainActivity is no longer a MAIN/LAUNCHER activity. Are you sure it's not just a matter of old shortcuts disappearing/failing to launch because of this? The difference between users may be caused by having different launcher apps (various manufacturers or manually installed). If you have some helpful users, you could ask them to 1: check the app drawer for the app, and 2: take a bugreport and send it to you (so that we may be able to see some logs of a failed launch).

Comment: @SnildDolkow i tried your suggestion and yes i got same error. Probably it is the reason. Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Glad to help. I posted my suggestion as an answer, so that people having similar issues may find it easier (for example, it will show that there's an answer in the search results).

Answer (score 0):

Your `MainActivity` is no longer a MAIN/LAUNCHER activity. Are you sure it's not just a matter of old shortcuts disappearing/failing to launch because of this?

The difference between users may be caused by having different launcher apps (various manufacturers or manually installed). If you have some helpful users, you could ask them to:

1. check the app drawer for the app, and
2. take a bugreport and send it to you (so that we may be able to see some logs of a failed launch)